# C++ design pattern for sockets

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, software-design

The goal is to be able to support both IPv4 and IPv6 for a rather complex application. At present, only IPv4 is handled. There is a class called `Socket` and a class called `TlsSocket` which extends from it. Let's say that `Socket` has a set of methods `M1,M2,....,M9`. `TlsSocket` overrides `M7, M8` and `M9`.

Given the current design I was thinking of making `Socket` an abstract class and extending it twice - `SocketIPv4` and `SocketIPv6` which would implement methods `M5 and M6` differently. However, then I would have to extend them twice again to have a TLS version for both IPv4 socket and IPv6 socket leading to code duplication. I was looking at the best design pattern for the problem at hand and I was convinced that the [decorator](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Decorator) design pattern would work best.

However, then `TlsSocket` would inherit from the abstract `Socket` class and then be composed of a concrete implementation of `Socket` (either IPv4 or IPv6). Therefore, I would essentially be initializing two Socket instances (one for composition and the other is TlsSocket itself) pointing to the same file descriptor. Everything should work fine but I am slightly uncomfortable initializing two socket instances pointing to the same file descriptor. Is there an alternative design pattern that I have missed and should consider?

Comment: You don't need two socket classes. One socket at the operating system level can handle both IPv4 and IPv6. Java sockets are an example. So no design pattern required.

Comment: @user207421- That is not true for all operating systems. Even if it were true, I would like to figure out how to design for such a case.

Comment: feels like you are re-inventing the wheel. Why don't you use [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)? Or at least did you check how boost implements it?

Comment: The pattern, which is used by all major libraries, is: acceptor/connector and reactor/proactor/act. Recommendation is to reuse existing libraries / patterns and to not reinvent the wheel.